# Aws Mixed Content Error https cloud front connects to ec2 instead to load balancer

Tags: angular, ssl, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

### Background:

Frontend:

I have an Angular project which is in a S3 Bucket. This bucket is connected to cloud front and the route 53 using ssl certificate. Https://www.example.de is working and has a valid SSL certificate.

Backend:

Besides, I have a Spring boot application which is running on an ec2 instance and relates to a load balancer using also ssl certificate. https://load-balancer.example.de/ is working and has a valid SSL certificate.

### Problem:

If I use the site https://www.example.de the front end is loading as expected, but I do not receive my data from the backend. In the developer console it says:

*Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.example.de/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://ec2.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/api/v1/...'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.*

I expected that my frontend is calling https://load-balancer.example.de/ like in my angular environment.prod.ts.

If I go my S3 Bucket and using that endpoint http://s3.eu-west-2... its working all fine. My front end is calling https://load-balancer.example.de/ and I get the right response.

What I am missing? Thanks in advance!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGSqs.jpg)